# C# add list of strings to combobox and when item is remove automatic affect to list

Tags: c#, list, binding, combobox, dataset

I want to add all strings from list to combobox, and when one of item is removed from ui, want to automatically to effect on list (that list remove also those selected string).

What is best tehnic for those kind of problems.

Example:

```
List<string> users = new List<string>(){ "frsUser", "secUser", "thrUser", "fouUser" };

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var user in users)
        cmbUser.Items.Add(user);
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbUser.Items.RemoveAt(cmbUser.SelectedIndex);
    // Should it be removed also here? 
    users.RemoveAt(cmbUser.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be easily done using a `BindingSource` that handles the interaction  between your collection of Combobox items and your list

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = users;
    c.DataSource = bs;
}
```

now at the button click event use this code

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(c.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;

    BindingSource bs = c.DataSource as BindingSource;
    bs.RemoveAt(c.SelectedIndex);

    // Just to show the updated list 
    foreach(string u in users)
        Console.WriteLine(u);
}
```